# if $g(t)=f(\frac {\cos (t)}t,\frac {\sin (t)}t)$ is a monotonic increasing function for $t>0$ then $\nabla f(0,0)=(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R $ be in $C^1$. suppose that $g(t)=f(\frac {\cos (t)}t,\frac {\sin (t)}t)$ is a monotonic increasing function for $t>0$. 
prove that $\nabla f(0,0)=(0,0)$.
I tried using the chain rule to acquire some information about $f$ but I'm not sure it is even the right direction. any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this assuming only that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0).$ Let $h(t) = g(1/t)=f(t\cos (1/t), t\sin (1/t)).$ Then $h$ is decreasing on $(0,\infty).$ Let $\nabla f(0,0) = (a,b).$ Then as $t\to 0,$

$$h(t)=f(0,0) + at\cos (1/t) + bt\sin (1/t) +o(t).$$

Thus $h(1/n\pi) = f(0,0) + a(-1)^n/n\pi +o(1/n).$ If $a\ne 0,$ this oscillates above and below $f(0,0)$ infinitely many times. This contradicts $h$ being decreasing. Hence $a=0.$ Same idea to get $b=0.$ Thus $\nabla f(0,0) = (0,0).$